# Passing param to meta title in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to pass route param to meta title but i have no idea how to do it. What i tried doing keeps returning undefined on the title tab:
[image: image result]

```js
{
  path:'/profile/:name',
  component: Profile,
  meta: { title: route.param.name + 'place' }
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easier in the component. I would try something like this on that component:

```
created: function () {
  document.title = this.$route.params.name + ' place'
}
```

and remove the title meta function.

```
{
  path:'/profile/:name',
  component: Profile,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to `props` instead:

```
{
  path:'/profile/:name',
  component: Profile,
  props: route => ({ title: route.param.name + 'place' })
}
```

Then just define the `title` prop in your `Profile` component:

```
props: {
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta as a function :

```
{
  path:'/profile/:name',
  component: Profile,
  meta: (route) => { title: route.params.name + 'place' }
}
```

then call it as a function of course in your template

```
this.$route.meta(this.$route)
```